# Sitecore get the number of placeholders

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

Is there a possibility to get the number of the placeholders in the page with a specified name. Fro example I have the my-placeholder1, my-placeholder2, my-placeholder3 in page and I need to know that I have 3 placeholders with that contain my-placeholder in their name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
        var placeholderName = "my-placeholder";
        var renderingReferences = Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
        var renderingsInPlaceholder = renderingReferences.Where(r => r.Placeholder.StartsWith(placeholderName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        var numberOfRenderingsInPlaceholder = renderingsInPlaceholder.Count();
```

This code is working just in case you have a component on these placeholders. So it will count placeholders with a component on it.

**Update** If you have multiple components on a placeholder it will count number of components.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to get the number of placeholder.

Sitecore generates pages dynamically. It can generated completely different output for `User A` and `User B`.

`my-placeholder2` can be inside a rendering which is hidden for one user and shown for another.

That's why you simply cannot tell how many placeholder with particular key will be rendered in a final page.

What you could try to do (which is **reaaaaaaaly evil** in my opinion) is to get the layout assigned to the page, get all the renderings and for all of them get their `cshtml` or `aspx` + `ascx` files and use some regex (another bad thing for html) to count placeholders with particular key.

But again - you can never be 100% sure that this is the number that will be used on the rendered page.

Comment: I have a rendering that has a placeholder inside. The problem is that the editor can add multiple times the rendering and I will end up with 2 placeholders with same name. I need somehow to be able to add the same section with different placeholder that I can control the name

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to use Dynamic Placeholders. There is a module for that on the market place: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/I/Integrated_Dynamic_Placeholders.aspx

Comment: @Radu just what Richard wrote: use dynamic placeholders. There are many implementations available online for free. And to be honest, I have no idea why it's not in Sitecore OOTB yet. It's what everyone wants and needs.

Comment: https://sitecoredeveloper.uservoice.com/forums/219013-general/filters/top @Radu vote here to have Dynamic Placeholders OOTB

Comment: I don't think that this approach will work for all case. For example what if inside one of cshtml views you have Html.Action() or Html.Partial() and inside it you have placeholder?

Comment: It is possible to check for all your files for partial views and look for placeholders inside them. But what you should do for actions? Write code analyzer?

Comment: @Anton that's what I wrote. This approach is a pure evil and you should not use it unless you have to somehow approximate number of placeholder and all your other options failed. Anyway, looks like dynamic placeholders are what Radu needs and this whole question lost its point.